# Efficient way to compute the correlation between each pair of columns in a matrix with Nan values?

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, nan, correlation

Suppose I have an `n`-by-`m` matrix `X`, and I want to get an `m`-by-`m` correlation matrix `Y`, where each element Y<sub>ij</sub> is the correlation between the i<sup>th</sup> column and the j<sup>th</sup> column.
However, the `X` matrix contains many `NaN` values at random positions.
The straight forward double loop method is:

```
Y = nan(m,m);
for i = 1:1:m
    for j = i:1:m
        subset = intersect(find(~isnan(X(:,i))),find(~isnan(X(:,j))));
        Y(i,j) = corr(X(subset,i),X(subset,j));
    end  
end
```

But this is too slow. Is there any more efficient ways?

Comment: This problem is underdefined. What is the correlation of a value with NaN? What is the correlation of NaN with NaN? Is the correlation of (0, 0, 0, … 0)  with (NaN,…NaN) smaller than the correlation of (1000, 1000, 1000, …, 1000) with  (NaN,…NaN)? I'd recommend *understanding* your data problem, solving that, and then correlating, and not just calculating *something* that has no meaning,

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you check carefully my code above, you can find that it has answered your question. The examples you give should end up with a correlation as NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized solution using matrix multiplication:

```
function Y = cornan(X)
    nans = isnan(X);
    nnans=~nans;
    X(nans)=0;
    sX=nnans.'*X;
    n=nnans.'*nnans;
    sX2=X.'*X;
    Y = (n.*sX2-sX.'.*sX)./sqrt((sX.^2-bsxfun(@times,n,diag(sX2).')).*(sX.'.^2-bsxfun(@times,n,diag(sX2))));
end
```

or as of MATLAB R2016b / Octave this can be shorter:

```
function Y = cornan(X)
    nans = isnan(X);
    nnans=~nans;
    X(nans)=0;
    sX=nnans.'*X;
    n=nnans.'*nnans;
    sX2=X.'*X;
    Y = (n.*sX2-sX.'.*sX)./sqrt((sX.^2-n.*diag(sX2).').*(sX.'.^2-n.*diag(sX2)));
end
```